# Symfony kernel.terminate event run command or service asynchronously

Tags: symfony, event-listener

I want to execute my service on kernel.terminate event to make it asynchronously . 
What i am doing in my controller before returning response is this

```
$this->eventDispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function (PostResponseEvent $event) use ($vat) {
    // Launch the job
    $command = new WebDriverCommand();
    $command->setContainer($this->container);
    $input = new ArrayInput(array('id' => $vat->getId()));
    $output = new NullOutput();
    $command->run($input, $output);

});
```

My question is : Is there a difference **between** running the command that executes my service **AND** calling the service directly without command ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely no difference. Your command must not have any logic anyway. Both event listeners and your commands should invoke a service anyway - be kind of a glue between the framework and your domain logic.

Your classes will in effect be easier to unit test and maintain.

Comment: emix, will there be a difference if i run it as a process? thank u in advance